# How to publsh an EXE installer to windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps, exe, windows-store

I have an exe installer of a windows desktop application. I want to publish this to the windows store with less or no code change. Is it possible?

I did some research and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You could use MSIX package tool to package your desktop app from any desktop installer into an MSIX package.

Before using the tool, you will need to check this document first:[Know your installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/know-your-installer). Makes sure your app is ready for the whole process.

Then you could use the tool to package your app. For more information about how to use the tool, please refer to this: [Create an MSIX package from any desktop installer (MSI, EXE, ClickOnce, or App-V)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package)